# Write linear constraints into linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-analysis

Suppose we have the following block matrix
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\
X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\
X_{31} &X_{32} & X_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $X_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},i,j=1,2,3$.For this block matrix,we have following constraints
$$
X_{12}+X_{21}=0\\
X_{13}+X_{13}=0\\
X_{23}+X_{32}=0
$$
Can we write the constraints as $\mathcal{A}(X)=0$,where $\mathcal{A}$ is a linear operator

Comment: Well, arguably you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb R^{3n \times3n} \to \mathbb R^{3n \times n}$ by

$\mathcal{A}(X)=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{12} + X_{21} \\
X_{13} + X_{31} \\
X_{23} + X_{32} 
\end{bmatrix}$